# 3-Tier: Sending data across Tiers

Tags: c#, oop, 3-tier

I have several visual studio projects related to a specific product. This product is a 3 tier application e.g. has Database, Workflow server and application server + web services.

Now let say this product or software is related to dealing of Fruits and Fruit Crates. What I am doing is that When a user creates or assembles a fruit crate, I am creating a object of FruitCrate and then instead of calling methods with several parameters I am creating FruitCrate object and sending it to DataAccess Project, to Workflow Projects and web services instead of parameters.

Now let say FruitCrate class or object looks like this,

```
Public Class FruitCrate 
{ 
Public string NumberOfFruits {get;set;}
Public string NameOfFruits {get;set;}
Public string ClientName{get;set;}
Public string PaymentDetails{get;set;}
.... let say 20 - 30 more properties added
}
```

Now in dataAccess I am creating object of FruitCrate and adding all values like this,

```
FruitCrate fc = new FruitCrate();
fc.NameOfFruits = "alksdjaslkdj";
...
fc.PropertyNumber30 = "asdasdasd";
```

But when I am sending this object to workflow it's like this, like sending only 10 properties

```
FruitCrate fc = new FruitCrate();
fc.NameOfFruits = "alksdjaslkdj";
...
fc.PropertyNumber10 = "asdasdasd";
```

**Being intermediate developer I am not just sure if this is right way of doing this ? Also can someone suggest me any resource where I can learn more about this type of coding I am just confused what to search for to improve this type of coding or application architecture.**

### Editing

Please try to understand I only added FruitCrate as an example this is not what I am actually doing, because of company privacy I cannot disclose exact scenario.

### What I want to know is, is there any better way to send across objects to different projects instead of sending methods with parameters ?

Please don't get confused with example.

Comment: I'd suggest that `FruitCrate` should implement `IEnumerable<Fruit>`

Comment: Or at least have a property like that. Number of fruits is just count. And Name of fruit is a property of the fruit.

Comment: Or `FruitCrate` could have a property called `Fruits` which is `IEnumerable<Fruit>` instead of the `NumberOfFruits` and `NameOfFruits` properties.

Comment: Please improve your title so it actually reflects your problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You've completely changed your question by editing it. Now I'm unsure what you are asking. However, before worrying about "interprocess communication", you ought to cover, "what is a collection."

Comment: Please do tell us more about those properties that are not sent!! We don't care about the secrets of your employer but until we know more about this part, we can only guess what the differences between those that get sent and those that are 'missing' or 'empty' (if that's what happens?) Are some values and others references?? (hint)

Answer (score 2):

From the little code we see, I think you should try to **partition** the problem domain into a number of smaller classes like:

- Fruit
- Customer
- Order
- Payment

etc..

These would then be combined in a `Crate`  with fewer properties and members of the other classes. These other classes should encapsulate their knowledge and their responsibilities.

This pattern is called `Composition` and is the recommended way to model a problem domain.

Don't try to put all your data into one FruitCrate class..

**Please note**: This answer is all about the OOP design side of your problem. Since you have now clarified that your main concern is *communication over the tier boundaries*, hopefully a few experts on this part of the question will jump in..!

Comment: ... or you'll get fruit salad! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you are right to ask the question, you are doing it wrong.

Going OO, lets define what a `Fruit` is,

```
public class Fruit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

now a `FruitCrate` is a collection of `Fruit`, one simple collection interface we can implement is `IReadOnlyList<T>`, so

```
public class FruitCrate : IReadOnlyList<Fruit>
{
    // Where we will hold the fruit internally.
    private readonly List<Fruit> fruits;

    // A constructor that takes in some fruit.
    public FruitCreate(IEnumerable<Fruit> fruits)
    {
        this.fruits = fruits.ToList();
    }

    // The rest is the implementation of IReadOnlyList<T>

    public int Count()
    {
       return this.fruits.Count;
    }

    Fruit this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.fruits[index];
        }
    }

    IEnumerator<Fruit> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.fruits.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Now, you can treat a `FruitCrate` like a read only collection of `Fruit` with an indexer. It will work with iterators like `foreach` and it has a `Count` property to tell you how many `Fruit` it contains.

Then, you add the `FruitCrate` specific attributes to your class,

```
public class FruitCrate : IReadOnlyList<Fruit>
{
   // ...

   public string ClientName { get; set; }

   public string PaymentDetails { get; set; }

   // ...
}
```

Comment: what the heck... inherit from collection and have a collection?

Comment: @MareInfinitus, is that a question?

Comment: Yes, I think you should elaborate why having a collection property is not enough here in your opinion.

Comment: @MareInfinitus, Well, since I was aiming for OO, I considered that a fruit box **is** a collection of fruit. The view that a fruit box **has** a collection is also correct, but is less intuitive, in my opinion. Either way, I wouldn't define a fruit box as having a fixed array of numbered slots that my or may not be null, as in the original question.